# Checksum Mismatch Error in Paytm Gateway PHP in Chrome Browser Only

Tags: php, payment-gateway, checksum, gateway, paytm

I have downlaoded Paytm Web sample kit php and integrate gateway in my site but i got an issue in chrome browser only which is checksum mismatched. In other browsers it works fine .
I use following code to generate checksum

```
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
// following files need to be included
require_once("./lib/config_paytm.php");
require_once("./lib/encdec_paytm.php");

$checkSum = "";
$paramList = array();

$ORDER_ID = $_POST["ORDER_ID"];
$CUST_ID = $_POST["CUST_ID"];
$INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID = $_POST["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"];
$CHANNEL_ID = $_POST["CHANNEL_ID"];
$TXN_AMOUNT = $_POST["TXN_AMOUNT"];

// Create an array having all required parameters for creating checksum.
$paramList["MID"] = PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID;
$paramList["ORDER_ID"] = $ORDER_ID;
$paramList["CUST_ID"] = $CUST_ID;
$paramList["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = $INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID;
$paramList["CHANNEL_ID"] = $CHANNEL_ID;
$paramList["TXN_AMOUNT"] = $TXN_AMOUNT;
$paramList["WEBSITE"] = PAYTM_MERCHANT_WEBSITE;
$paramList["CALLBACK_URL"] = "http://localhost/Paytm_Payment_Gateway-PHP/pgResponse.php";

/*
$paramList["CALLBACK_URL"] = "http://localhost/PaytmKit/pgResponse.php";
$paramList["MSISDN"] = $MSISDN; //Mobile number of customer
$paramList["EMAIL"] = $EMAIL; //Email ID of customer
$paramList["VERIFIED_BY"] = "EMAIL"; //
$paramList["IS_USER_VERIFIED"] = "YES"; //

*/

//Here checksum string will return by getChecksumFromArray() function.
$checkSum = getChecksumFromArray($paramList,PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY);



?>
```

and following to verify checksum

```
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

// following files need to be included
require_once("./lib/config_paytm.php");
require_once("./lib/encdec_paytm.php");

$paytmChecksum = "";
$paramList = array();
$isValidChecksum = "FALSE";

$paramList = $_POST;
$paytmChecksum = isset($_POST["CHECKSUMHASH"]) ? $_POST["CHECKSUMHASH"] : ""; //Sent by Paytm pg

//Verify all parameters received from Paytm pg to your application. Like MID received from paytm pg is same as your application�s MID, TXN_AMOUNT and ORDER_ID are same as what was sent by you to Paytm PG for initiating transaction etc.
$isValidChecksum = verifychecksum_e($paramList, PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY, $paytmChecksum); //will return TRUE or FALSE string.


if ($isValidChecksum == "TRUE") {
    echo "<b>Checksum matched and following are the transaction details:</b>" . "<br/>";
```

Have a look to help me